# How To Deactivate the Shop

Tags: shopping

For certain store views, we do not want to offer a shopping functionality at all.

Products should be shown (as a catalog), but not the possibility to add to the cart.

How can we disable the shopping functionalities of Magento by configuration?

UPDATE:

- Add To Cart Button can be removed using the `catalog_product_is_salable_after` (thanks to @fmrng's answer)
- It is pretty tough to remove the "out of stock" notice from all templates...

Comment: I am hereby reserving the word "AntiShop" for my extension :-)

Comment: We did this about a year and a half ago for an electrical parts manufacturer wanting to use Magento EE strictly as a catalogue for wholesale customers. Unfortunately, I don't have anything to offer though... Been far too long, and another of my devs worked on it. :)

Comment: @davidalger You'd better made that open source :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Disable Module Output for example of Mage_Checkout
- We might need some fine tuning of the templates

*EDIT, also based on other answers (I am developing a FOSS extension for that)*

Events:

- `catalog_block_product_status_display` (for product detail)
- `catalog_product_is_salable_after`

Comment: -1 (I want better answers)

Comment: I think this might be the best solution but just disable the extension from backend and not through XML because of dependencies.

Comment: Actually I think this is the best solution. I've used it once. I just needed to add some `if` statements in some templates (product list, view, wishlist, compare list) to check Mage_Checkout output is disabled (just like the wishlist button has). By the way...I think Magento should have these `if` statements by default. you may also need to disable the output `Mage_Sales` to make it clean. +1 on this, but if you decide to take this approach please list the templates you modify. (I've forgot some of them).

Comment: Looks like I also need @fmrng for hiding the add to cart button ... making an extension but will also share the basics here.

Answer (score 1):

What about an observer on `catalog_product_is_salable_after`? I'm not saying it's an elegant and bulletproof solution, but it would actually be quite easy to enable/disable and it definitely hides all 'Add to cart' buttons in frontend in one blow.

Comment: Mostly the cart buttons would be replaced to "Out of Stock" due to the templates.

Comment: Sorry, I only tested it on enterprise/default theme before posting it and noticed no problem. Probably in base/default it's like you said. Anyway, the products are in fact 'not salable', so it would still make sense to define them as such.